# TSSOP pads lifting when soldernig

Tags: soldering

I am just soldering my first ever TSSOP-16, on my first perfect toner-transfer board, and when I am tinning the TSSOP pads some of them are lifting up.  Which of these is most likely responsible?

1. The soldering iron is too hot (it's an uncontrollable 30w)
2. The board is inferior (it was cheap stuff from Maplin)
3. I have Parkinson's <sup>(Apologies to anyone who has a relative / friend with Parkinson's - no offense intended)</sup>
4. Something I haven't thought of?
5. All of the above

It's not the end of the world - the pads have remained pretty much in position and I have successfully soldered in the TSSOP chip, but it would be nice to know why it happened so I can stop it happening the next time.

Comment: The EEV Blog has a nice video tutorial on soldering: http://www.eevblog.com/2011/07/02/eevblog-183-soldering-tutorial-part-2/

Comment: Use more flux!!

Comment: I have no more flux - only what is in the solder.

Comment: @Matt - My dad's dad, my mom's mom, as well as a deceased great aunt, all have Parkinson's.  I'll let you know in 40 years or so how the disease affects soldering ability. No offense taken.

Comment: @Kevin My Gran had it, and my Mom may well develop it.

Answer (score 7):

My first thought is inferior board. It never happened to boards we purchased from a professional PCB shop.
The iron is also a suspect. 30W is not a particularly high value, but the fact that it isn't temperature controlled means that it becomes very hot, no matter how low-power it is. The iron's power determines how fast heat can be drained from the iron without dropping temperature, and SMT pads don't draw much heat, so the iron will be and remain too hot. A temperature controlled iron is a must for decent soldering, both SMT and PTH.

Answer (score 4):

If you are planning to do more SMD work I certainly would recommend buying a tempearture controlled iron. Mine costed ~ $40, so it probably won't empty your wallet.

I have no experience with Maplin, inferior board quality might be an issue.

How long did you touch any individual pad? When I am doing semi-mass production a single pad takes less than a second. But that is on a pre-tinned (or rather pre-golded) board, with solder mask (which might act as additional glue).

If you make your own PCBs it might help to make the pads as large as possible, preferrably extending beyond the area you intend to solder.

If you are into more SMD work you might consider using solder paste and a solder oven. temperature controlling a small toaster oven might be a nice project.

Comment: The pad was touched for < ¼s.  I have my eye on a £80 solder rework station on ebay - temp controlled iron and a hot air blower in one unit.  I have also seen a video of someone who made their own reflow oven from a toaster oven - I am tempted to give it a go.

Comment: ¼s is too short for proper soldering. Many people solder the wrong way (it's not taught in college), and apply the solder to the iron. You have to heat up the pad and apply the solder to that. It will never be hot enough after ¼s.

Comment: It was, and I did.  And it my day it was taught in college (and I was top of the class).  Iron to pad, solder to pad, whoomf.  But in this case it caused the pad to lift.  Remember, this is TSSOP, so the pad is about 1.5mm long by 0.1mm wide ;)

Comment: @Matt - that means the temperature definitely was too high! The temperature controlled iron should be before the oven on your shopping list!

Comment: I am leaning that way, yes.  It would be more useful (and smaller).  I have some better copper-clad on order from RS to try out, but I don't like this iron much any way.

Comment: @Matt, did you mean 0.25mm? :)

Comment: @avakar I meant bloody small.

Comment: @Matt I wish I went to college in your day...

Comment: If 1/4s of soldering caused the pad to come off your tip temperature is definitely too high. Get a temperature controlled iron now! Don't worry too much about selecting the perfect one, any temperature controlled iron will be much better than what you use now.

Comment: @Wouter - Too hot, yes. But also lousy board quality. 1/4s is just a quick touch, no traces should come loose in that time, regardless of temperature!

Answer (score 1):

I tack down two leads on opposite corners, whilst holding the chip in position, using my smallest tip cartridge in my Metcal system, apply plenty of jelly flux, and drag-solder the leads with a mini-hoof cartridge. The Metcal system was bought second-hand and was quite cheap. They have exceptional temperature control, I never have problems with pads lifting on my home-made PCBs and commercial ones.

The Metcal system I use comprises an old STSS power unit with the later MX-500 handpiece and cartridges. It cost me £120.

Comment: Metcal makes the most awesome soldering irons ever. They heat up in just a few seconds, and the physics of the tip itself controls the temperature very well. That means that you have to get different tips for different temperatures, but in practice this isn't really a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

If you're tinning the board with your soldering iron, your
problem is that the small trace is sticking to the iron.
The surface tension of the solder is a large force for small features,
and the copper-to-board glue has a small area.  Large beats small.
Adhesion might be better with a larger pad, but the usual solution is to use a bit of adhesive to hold the component down to the board, then flux and solder the joints (the component would have to lift, too, in this case).   In hand-solder application, I've also held the component down with a bamboo stick while applying heat.